# Pandas Data Frame not Appending

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-redshift, databricks

I am trying to append dataframes via for loop.

**CODE**

```
def redshift_to_pandas(sql_query,**kwargs):
# pass a sql query and return a pandas dataframe
 cur.execute(sql_query)
 columns_list = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]
 data = pd.DataFrame(cur.fetchall(),columns=columns_list)
 return data
```

Input -
`all_schema = [('backup')]`

Loop -

```
try:
 if len(all_schema) == 0:
  raise inputError("The Input has no schema selected. EXITING")
 else:
  modified_schemadf=pd.DataFrame(columns=['columns_name','status'])
  
  for i in range(len(all_schema)):
    #print (redshift_to_pandas("select '"+all_schema[i]+"' as columns_name,(select exists ( select distinct table_schema from information_schema.tables where table_schema like '%"+all_schema[i]+"')) as status",mechanism='append'))
    modified_schemadf.append(redshift_to_pandas("select '"+all_schema[i]+"' as columns_name,(select exists ( select distinct table_schema from information_schema.tables where table_schema like '%"+all_schema[i]+"')) as status",mechanism='append'))
    print (modified_schemadf)

except inputError as e:
   print(e.message)
   logger.error("UNEXPECTED INPUT FOUND, Please check the I/P List . EXITING")
  
print (modified_schemadf)
```

I feel the issue is very obvious but i dont seem to find the issue.

Here is the o/p -

[image: Result Picture]

So the the first print ( commented out ), does return me the correct result.
the next steps i.e appending the result to the declared dataframe ( name - modified_schemadf) is the problem area. When i print its value , it still throws a empty dataframe. For some reason the appending isnt happening.

When the code enters **else** , i.e when the input is legit, there will be empty dataframe created called modified_schemadf. To this empty dataframe, there will be as many number of appends as there are inputs.

Thanks in Advance.

Please dont mind the indentations, copying might have affected them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't the issue just that you don't assign the appended dataframe? Try changing this line

```
modified_schemadf.append(redshift_to_pandas("select '"+all_schema[i]+"' as columns_name,(select exists ( select distinct table_schema from information_schema.tables where table_schema like '%"+all_schema[i]+"')) as status",mechanism='append'))
```

to this line

```
modified_schemadf = modified_schemadf.append(redshift_to_pandas("select '"+all_schema[i]+"' as columns_name,(select exists ( select distinct table_schema from information_schema.tables where table_schema like '%"+all_schema[i]+"')) as status",mechanism='append'))
```